# SharePoint Active Directory Import vs SharePoint Profile Synchronization

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile, active-directory-import

I want to import only one OU from the active directory, I don't need to import all the users to SharePoint. I read some articles mentioning that the SharePoint Active Directory Import can be used to import all the users without specifying specific groups. Could someone tell me what is the right choice please, the SharePoint Active Directory Import or the SharePoint Profile Synchronization.

Answer (score 3):

Its depend on upon your requirement, but you can configure the only OU which u want to import with either ADI or UPA Sync. I would Prefer the ADI...here are a couple of Advantages.

Active Directory Import:

- One way of import, you can't export values to AD
- It's Fast then FIM's two-way sync
- Easy to configure.
- You can schedule incremental every 5 min.
- You can Apply the LDAP Filters to exclude the users from importing.
- You can select which OU you want to import.

But you can't import the Complex AD attribute with AD Import i.e **Profile Picture.**

If you want to import Profile picture then UPA Sync is the option.

http://johnnaguib.blogspot.com/2014/04/sharepoint-2013-user-profile.html

Something you need to think

- It imports non user objects as well, like computer accounts.
- If you have an OU which has both Computer & Users objects, then both
  are imported in UPA. However this is not the case with FIM based
  synchronization
- If you select only few users under an OU, then import process does
  not bring in those users to UPA. It only imports all users in an OU &
  whole OU has to be selected .

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2015/03/04/sharepoint-2013-active-directory-import-and-known-behaviors/